# Why java ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception Extends IndexOutofBound Exception not Throwable?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance

I have a doubt in `Exception with Inheritance`.

**why**

`public class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException extends IndexOutOfBoundsException`

and then

`public class IndexOutOfBoundsException extends RuntimeException`

and then

`public class RuntimeException extends Exception`

**Why Not**

`public class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException extends Exception`

Why this hierarchy is maintained.. Any guidance will be helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is intended to keep an hierarchy that makes sense, and also serves to group related exceptions.

Also, if you know what an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is, and someone gives you another exception that extends this one, you can immediately gather information from this fact alone. In this case, that some of the involved objects keep indexes within a certain range.

If every exception extended `Exception` or `RuntimeException` (whether its occurrence should be checked or non-checked), and its name was somewhat obscure, you'd have no clue as to what it might represent.

Consider the following code.

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        myCharArray[i] = myString.charAt(i);
    }
}
catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Do you need to treat string indexes differently?
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Perhaps you need to do something else when the problem is the array.
}
catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Or maybe they can both be treated equally.
    // Note: you'd have to remove the previous two `catch`.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That's because `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is also a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and `RuntimeException`.

In your suggestion, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will only be `Exception`.

So if you want to catch only `RuntimeException` for example, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` won't be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a *subtype* of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

That is where Inheritance comes into picture, and helps to keep levels of Inheritance clean and focused, with main goal of extensibility. There cane be wrong Indexes not only in Array but even in String etc. HTH